# When a function ends are its local variables deallocated?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

If not does that mean that I would have to end each function by deleting all local variables if I wanted to prevent 100% of memory leak?

Comment: understanding local scope is vital to "getting" C++. Look for a tutorial with the words `scope` and `destructor` in it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All objects have an associated storage duration. A storage duration describes how long the storage for an object is kept around. Local variables that are not references introduce an object with automatic storage duration, which means that the storage of those objects is automatically destroyed at the end of its scope.

Reference type variables do not introduce an object and may not even require storage of their own, but they still have storage duration (§3.7/3). If a reference does require storage, it will be released according to the reference's storage duration.

As such, any kind of local variable declaration will not leak. In fact, you cannot `delete` an object with automatic storage duration. That is only used for objects with dynamic storage duration, which are allocated using `new`.

Comment: This still leaves it open what happens to reference variables. They are not objects, but they also cause no leeks.

Comment: @KerrekSB Neither pointers nor references cause leeks; only dynamic allocation can cause a leek.  But if you write things like `MyType& var = *new MyType;`, you can leak with a reference as well.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I realize that. I was referring to the space taken up by `var` itself. The answer doesn't seem to cover it, since `var` is not an object.

Comment: @JamesKanze: In particular, I would like to see a reference to 3.7/3.

Comment: @KerrekSB Added a paragraph on that. Thanks for highlighting it.

Comment: @KerrekSB  OK.  I hadn't realized that you were talking about the memory of the reference: references may or may not require memory, and it's up to the compiler to ensure that any memory they may require never leaks (unless it is part of a larger object which is leaked).

Answer (score 8):

The local variables that are allocated on stack, i.e. without using memory allocation functions or operators like `malloc` and `new`, are deleted automatically. All other variables have to be deleted by using `delete` as they are stored on heap.

Comment: Simply explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If you manually allocate memory you must deleted it whenever you need,

Example:

```
char* foo()
{
    char* manually_allocated_char  = new char(); // this will 'live' outside the function
    char  autamically_allocated    = 'a'; // this will be 'deleted'
    return manually_allocated_char;
}


void main()
{
    char* a_new_char = foo();
    delete a_new_char; // You must free memory you have allocated for not having memory leaks
}
```

Comment: Note that this example is good for illustration only; try not to strive for writing code this way normally. In general, try to keep your `new`s and `delete`s together. If you can't do that and absolutely must do something like this, then comment comment comment!

Comment: What about static variables? They survive the end of the scope. Must I delete them when they're no longer needed?

Comment: @MatheusRocha, it depends, if you want the function to "remember some state" better to leave it as it is (if you use `new` operator), for other statically allocated variables without using `new` it is not necesary.

Answer (score 4):

Dynamically allocated memory using malloc, realloc, new, and new[] must be deleted. These are in heap memory. Others would get automatically deallocated.

Comment: Also note that when using smart pointers or auto_ptr, you're still allocating dynamic memory on the heap using new, but the clean-up is managed for you automatically.

Comment: In this case, what is the real advantage of using `malloc` or `new`?