# Returning reference to local variable without trivial conversion

Tags: c++, reference, g++

I am quite a newbie to the C++ programming, but this question keeps on spinning in my head. I understand that returning reference to a local variable in a function is illegal, i.e. compiling this code snippet:

```
inline int& funref() {
    int    a = 8;
    return a;     // not OK!
}
```

results in a warning from the compiler and then a runtime error. But then, why does this piece of code get compiled without any warnings and run without error?

```
inline int& funref() {
    int  a    = 8;
    int& refa = a;
    return refa;   // OK!
}

int main() {
    int& refa = funref();
    cout << refa;
}
```

My compiler is g++ on Linux Fedora platform.

Comment: I assume that you're asking about why the second "working" program doesn't generate a warning or error like the first program, even though they both have the same problem?

Comment: If you want a warning from GCC, you're free to improve it with a patch.

Comment: Because it's undefined behaviour. Anything could happen: it might print "8", it might print garbage and it might cause your program to communicate with and launch nuclear missiles.

Comment: What version of g++ are you using?  I did find a bug report for an older version

Comment: @NathanOliver, from what I read I have: gcc version 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1) (GCC)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes, that is the actual point of my question. Nevertheless, thanks to all for your helpful comments.

Comment: @Sonar Okay.  That bug does not apply then.

Comment: That's why we use always multiple compilers to get more errors/warnings. clang complains with: main.cpp:7:12: warning: reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'a' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address] and: main.cpp:6:10: note: binding reference variable 'refa' So we run our builds for product, development and especially for unit tests with all compilers which are available for the project and platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's still wrong, it just happens to be working by (un)happy coincidence.

This code has undefined behaviour with all the usual caveats (it might always work, it might always work until it's too late to fix, it might set fire to your house and run away with your betrothed).

The compiler isn't required to issue a diagnostic (warning or error message) for every possible mistake, just because it isn't always possible to do so. Here, at least your current version of g++ hasn't warned. A different compiler, or a different version of g++, or even the same version with different flags, might warn you.

Comment: Probably the compiler "thinks": I know `a` is a local variable, so a reference to it cannot (shouldn't) be returned. It is, though, perfectly legal to assign a reference to `a` to `refa`. However, tracking that `refa` "happens" to refer to a local would be extremely hard (and possibly impossible) in the general case, so does not/cannot generate a warning when `refa` is used as the return value.

Comment: Very likely - a static code analysis would track this dependency, but it seems reasonable for a compiler not to bother.

Comment: @Useless Interestingly enough, that static code analyzer, embedded in VS2013 still, doesn't flag this issue, even with All Rules enabled.

Comment: @Useless I guess it could potentially track "ref to a local" in a similar way to potentially unitialised variables, but -- as you say -- it's not unreasonable not to, once you go beyond "trivial" cases (e.g. where the assignment of `refa` depends on run-time values).

Comment: A follow-up question then. Does `refa` in `funref`have an automatic storage duration (as `a` does) and get destroyed after the exit from `funref`? And does `refa` have any storage of its own here?

Comment: What would it mean for a reference to be destroyed? A reference is an alias for some other object, which has its own lifetime. As an alias, it's generally more useful to think about the scope within which its name is visible. The exception is when a reference keeps an otherwise-anonymous temporary alive.

Comment: @Sonar In a sense, yes. (Warning: loose analogies ahead!)  `a` is "a box" in which the values `8` or `42` etc. can be stored. The box is created on the stack when the function is called and disposed of when it exits. Similarly, `refa` is "a box" in which "a reference to `a`" can be stored. This box is also created/disposed as the function enters/exits.  The "reference to `a`" is (essentially) the location of the `a` box on the stack, which is why it becomes invalid after the function has returned.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers. I asked, because I've come over this explanation to another SO question:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21832995/7785836)

I wondered whether `refa` actually outlives `a` (strange for an alias, I agree) and maybe that is why g++ is not complaining.

Answer (score -3):

The reason why you can't return a reference to a local variable is because the local variable will get wiped when your function returns. Simply put, the compiler prevents you from referencing garbage data.

However, the compiler isn't bulletproof (as shown in your example #2).

It does work for retrieving a singleton instance, though.

```
inline int& funref()
    {
    static int* p_a = nullptr;
    if (nullptr == p_a)
        p_a = new int(8);

    return *p_a;
    }
```

this case is valid because the memory pointed by p_a remains valid after the function returns.

Comment: The OP appears to be asking "why is the compiler not bullet proof" rather than "why does the rule exist".

Comment: Why not just `static int a = 8; return a;`?

Comment: By stating my question I did mean to ask: "am I right that both versions of funref() are faulty and is it just the compiler's <<ignorance>> in this case". I understand that the local variable gets destroyed after exit from funref. Anyway, thanks for help!